# How to replace a regex pattern with another regex pattern in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to replace a regex pattern to another regex pattern in Scala, is there any direct functionality that can be used for it? Or should I find the each regex one by one and change it.

```
    val string1 = "(value1 + value2) + max(value3, max(value4, value5))"     
    //convert to
    val string2 = "(value1 + value2) + lmax[(value3, lmax[(value4, value5)])]"
```

So, I want to convert string1 to string2, basically converting

```
     max(something) => lmax[(something)]
```

Sorry, if this is very naive question. I am pretty new to Scala.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your question has very little to do with Scala. It's much more of a regex problem.

Secondly, you're not really replacing a regex pattern with another regex pattern.  You're trying to handle nested capture groups, which regex isn't very good at.

In fact, it's worse than that.  You're trying to capture a group that is delimited by matching parentheses.  Again, regex isn't good at that.

Consider this string.

```
"value1 + max((value2 + value3), max(value4, value5))"
```

Now you've got two sets of parentheses within the outer capture group. The first set is not a target, and should be ignored, while the second set is a target that should be captured and replaced.  Not a trivial task.

And, of course, if someone puts a line break in the code then you're hosed.

```
"max(value12
   + value13)"
```

It looks to me like regex isn't the tool for this job. (But I've been wrong before....)

Comment: Then I should use stack based evaluation for it right?

Comment: You need to write a parser.